# Open new tab on table row click

Tags: jquery, html

```
if (/view/.test(self.location.href)) {
    $('.table tbody tr ').click(function() {
        var href = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
        if (href) {
            window.open(href, '_blank');
        }
    })
    $('.table tr').find('td:first').on('click', function(e) {
        // e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
}
```

After table row click browser open 3 tabs, where can be problem ? I want open only 1 tab.

Comment: Guess you ran through this piece of code three times, thereby registering three event handlers.

Comment: Is there any event on column level ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this and you will understand your issue:

alert($('.table tbody tr ').length);

Edited:

Sorry I didn't get your question. you have to do this to fix the issue:

```
if (/view/.test(self.location.href)) {
    $('.table tbody tr ').unbind('click');
    $('.table tbody tr ').click(function() {
```

**Explained (as the audience demands)**

Basically, it may be the case that you load it dynamically or many times, so it will bind the click action, in this case 3 times, which cause to open 3 tabs, using unbind delete this previous bind so it will only bind the event once.

Comment: Can you please explain that a bit more?

Comment: "This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, [...]"